# Iphone SDK 4.0 -->> simulator just sits there and doesn't load the ap

Tags: iphone, xcode, operating-system, ios4

I have started learning iphone apps development. However when I build and run the project, the simulator opens with new app icon.  When I click on the new app icon  ...nothing happens.

-->> simulator just sits there and doesn't load the app

Any help will be appreciated.

Marty

Comment: Nothing happens as in the simulator just sits there and doesn't load the app, or nothing happens as in the program crashes immediately upon being opened?  If the latter, then could be that there's an error in the program causing it to crash on startup.

Comment: You mean if you close the app on the simulator and try to re-open it, it won't re-open?

Comment: Yes  simulator just sits there and doesn't load the app

Comment: When you "build and run", does anything shown in the debuuger console? (cmd-shift-R).

Comment: Nothing. It runs successfully. It opens the simulator. The icon is there in the simulator. When I click the icon...simulator opens blank screen

Comment: Please post your code so that your question can become answerable

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not my code. I got it from the book I am studying from.  Here it is:-

```
#import "basicViewController.h"

@implementation basicViewController

@synthesize txtName;
@synthesize lblMessage;

- (IBAction) doSomething;
{
    NSString *msg =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@", txtName.text];
    [lblMessage setText:msg];
    [msg release];


}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end

//------------------------



#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface basicViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtName;
    IBOutlet UILabel *lblMessage;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *txtName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lblMessage;

- (IBAction) doSomething;



@end
```